# Creating a 3d figure from four boundary curves in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d, coordinates

I have a set of four curves. I want to color/shade/fill the area between them or create a 3d volume. Each curve is represented by a set of [x,y,z] coordinates. I am new to python and I just need to visualize this result for my research, but cannot seem to be find any clear example about how to do this or even if it is possible to do something like this. Any help is appreciated. Currently I am just filling the space with hundreds of other similar curves, but it does not look very appealing.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o5FB.png)
[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaGI4.png)

I am using the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
axyz = fig.gca(projection='3d')
plt.axis('equal')




for i in range (0,4): #plotting the four curves
    x=[]
    y=[]
    z=[]
    with open(str(i)+".csv") as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in readCSV:
            x.append(float(row[0]))
            y.append(float(row[1]))
            z.append(float(row[3]))
    axyz.plot(x, y, z)


axyz.view_init(elev=11, azim=-104)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to plot more lines, you need more data, right? So it's not too clear what you want to ask here.

Comment: I just want to highlight the volume between these curves, most suitably by drawing surfaces between the curves, just like walls between the edges of a room make a volume.

Comment: In that case you probably need a `plot_surface` plot, instead of lines.

Comment: Any link to an example or something would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+plot_surface

Comment: Yeah, well.  I came here after google ended me nowhere.. thank you though.